# Juntar duas ou mais covariáveis no R

Tags: data, data.frame, r

Tenho uma base de dados com vários ID (linhas) e nas colunas as covariáveis. Essas covariáveis se repetem em outras colunas com informações diferentes sobre o mesmo ID. Como juntar essas covariáveis utilizando R em uma única coluna e criando mais linhas para cada valor agrupado?

Exemplo:

```
id      var1   var2
1       21.0   160.0
2       25.0   100.0
```

Resulta em:

```
id      var
1       21.0   
1       160.0
2       25.0
2       100.0
```

Comment: Fabiel, o que exatamente você quer dizer com juntar essas covariaveis? E qual e a razão para isto? No caso, você se refere ao group by? Ou você esta falando de agrupar estes modelos em um mesmo _dataframe_?

Comment: Seja var1, var2, var3 e var4. O que quero é unir todas essas variáveis em apenas uma variável, seria um "colar" var2 embaixo do var1 e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Acredito que compreendi. Apenas para ficar mais claro e eu ter certeza: As 4 colunas serão agrupadas em uma UNICA em troca de mais linhas com o mesmo id preenchido? Ex: ID1 ,var1, var2,..., var4. Ficaria: ID1, var1; ID1, var2; ...; ID1, var4?

Comment: Isso. O ID vai acabar se repetindo em outras linhas para fazer a compensação dessa única variável que terei.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fabiel,

Para esta condição, existe um pacote chamador de `reshape2` que te auxília com a função melt.

```
install.packages("reshape2")
```

Para este caso, utilizarei o dataset incluso no RSTUDIO chamado de `mtcars`:

```
> data(mtcars) 

> head(mtcars[order(mtcars$rn)],4)
                       rn  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
    1:        AMC Javelin 15.2   8  304 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
    2: Cadillac Fleetwood 10.4   8  472 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
    3:         Camaro Z28 13.3   8  350 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
    4:  Chrysler Imperial 14.7   8  440 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
```

Para efeitos de demonstração, agruparemos a coluno **gear** e **carb**.

O comando melt realiza basicamente o agrupamento de todas as colunas não listadas, conforme o seguinte:

```
mtcars_dataframe_melt <- melt(mtcars, id.vars=c("rn","mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt","qsec","vs","am"))
```

No caso, todas as colunas exceto as que você deseja agrupar devem ser listadas. A saída (ordenada) é a seguinte:

```
>head(mtcars_dataframe_melt[order(mtcars_dataframe_melt$rn),],8)
                       rn  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am variable value
    23        AMC Javelin 15.2   8  304 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0     gear     3
    55        AMC Javelin 15.2   8  304 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0     carb     2
    15 Cadillac Fleetwood 10.4   8  472 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0     gear     3
    47 Cadillac Fleetwood 10.4   8  472 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0     carb     4
    24         Camaro Z28 13.3   8  350 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0     gear     3
    56         Camaro Z28 13.3   8  350 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0     carb     4
    17  Chrysler Imperial 14.7   8  440 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0     gear     3
    49  Chrysler Imperial 14.7   8  440 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0     carb     4
```

As colunas são agrupadas em uma coluna de nome "Value" e é criada uma coluna "variable" que indica o nome da coluna referente ao valor inserido.